# Australia Skilled Independent Visa (189) coming back after first entry

Tags: visa, australia, skilled-migration

If a person arrive in Australia on Skilled Independent Visa 189 before First Entry Date, and come back to the home country, stay back for 1 year. 
Does it have any impact of going back to Australia?

Such that the First Entry requirement is full-filled and don't want to plan complete movement in a hurry.